# ios 7 : Customize center button in UItabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have designed UITabbarController in storyboard. I'm pretty much confused to customize the center tabbar button with Unique background image.

Please help me out on this

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to create custom tab bar

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-quick-tip-creating-a-uitabbar-application-with-storyboards--mobile-10449